# Why Python Tcp client send close sign automatically?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I guess `Python` automatically send a close sign when shuts down(ctr+c) the client.

**python tcp server**

```py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 12345        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            #if not data:break
            conn.sendall(data)
            print(data)
```

**python tcp client**

```py
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 12345        # The port used by the server

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', data)
#s.close()
```

When executing this code,
the server continues to receive *null data (maybe close sign)* by the client that ended without closing.

```
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 55305)
b'Hello, world'
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
...
```

---

This error occurs when run `node.js` client and shutdown(ctr+c) without close sign.
The python tcp server occurs error but not print null.
**node.js tcp client**

```js
const Net = require('net');

const client = new Net.Socket();
client.setEncoding('utf8');

client.connect({ port: 12345, host: '127.0.0.1' })
client.write('Hello, world');
/*client.end()*/
```

```py
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 56685)
b'Hello, world'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../server.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = conn.recv(1024)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I know that the server and the client need to send and receive the exit sign,
but I wonder why the Python client automatically sends the close sign when it is closed.
Where can I get information about this?

Comment: When the process ends the OS will close all sockets left open.

Comment: By "close sign" do you mean shutting down the TCP connection?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz close sign mean use `socket.close()` and send  close packet to server.

Comment: @MiryangJung I think you may be a bit confused. The `socket.close()` function only closes the file descriptor. It doesn't necessarily send any packets or close the connection itself. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and you'll see that `socket.close()` closes the descriptor and doesn't necessarily do anything to the TCP connection. It does no longer allow this particular socket object to reference the connection, but others still might. You may be thinking of `socket.shutdown()` which does shutdown the TCP connection.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understood what you said. Thank you.